# Volumes of Rotation-- space and its compliment don't have same volume in same boundaries

Tags: calculus, integration, volume

These two problems come from the MIT 18.01 problem sets. I believe they describe two complimentary spaces in the same boundary, so I would have thought they had the same volume. They don't. I feel insane.

Consider the volume of the region described by $ 0 \le y \le x^2,$ $x \le 1 $ rotated around the y axis. I had no problem finding the answer: it's $ \frac\pi 2 $.

Already I feel crazy, because the volume of the cylinder described by those boundaries is $ \pi$-- meaning that the space described above is half the volume. But, just for the area between 0 and 1, the non-rotated space described is $\frac13$ the area of the corresponding square. I would imagine the volume would have the same ratio, but it doesn't. That's kind of a side issue. Here's the kicker:

Consider the volume of the region described by $ \sqrt x \le y \le 1,$ $x \ge 0 $ rotated around the y axis. Again, the answer isn't hard to get-- it's $ \frac\pi 5 $. Of course, $y = x^2$ is just the inverse of $y=\sqrt x$ between 0 and 1. In that domain and range, the area below $y = x^2$ has the same volume as the area above $y=\sqrt x$. Shouldn't they have the same volume?

But they don't. One of these statements is false, but I don't know which one it is:

1. The two volumes described above are compliments where $-1 \le x \le 1$ and $0 \le y \le 1$.
2. Complimentary volumes in the same space should be equivalent.

Help? And if someone could clear up my confusion described above about $\frac 1 3$ of the area can create $\frac 1 2$ of the volume when rotated, I'd really appreciate it. Like I said, I feel crazy. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first case you have more mass at the edge of the cylinder.
In the second case you have your mass concentrated at the hub.

The two volumes are not equal even if every cross section cut through the center is identical.

Comment: Thanks. I don't know why it didn't occur to me that the "fat" part gets rotated for a greater distance in first instance than in the second.